# ASP.NET MVC3 Entity Framework Entity not updating correctly

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3

I made a test program for something totally unrelated to Entity Framework and what I thought would be an easy integration turned out to be troublesome. I have a DB Table called "**TestEntry**" which holds four data fields [ Id (uniqueidentifier), EId (uniqueidentifier), Name, Data ], these are unrelated to any other database tables and are standalone.

The issue is a simple update which is defined as such:

```
    EDMEntities _db = new EDMEntities();

    public List<TestEntry> GetEntities()
    {
        return _db.TestEntries.ToList();
    }
    public void EditEntry(TestEntry newEntry)
    {
        TestEntry entry = _db.TestEntries.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == newEntry.Id);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(newEntry.Name)) { entry.Name = newEntry.Name; }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(newEntry.Data)) { entry.Data = newEntry.Data; }

        if (entry.EntityState == System.Data.EntityState.Modified)
        {
            _db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

After stepping through it I noticed:

- Neither **entry.Name** nor **entry.Data** gets updated with the values from **newEntry**
- The EntityState remains unchanged thus not entering the conditional

Any ideas on what this could be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to negate the conditionals.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(newEntry.Name))
```

Note the exclamation mark.

Comment: Do you mean **entry.EntityState != System.Data.EntityState.Modified** as that would still not yield any results because the actual entity does not get updated.

Comment: @Cosmin Parculescu: No. Where you are checking if the newEntity has values is the problem.

Comment: Sometimes it just takes a fresh pair of eyes to catch them.

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't it be:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(newEntry.Name)) { entry.Name = newEntry.Name; }
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(newEntry.Data)) { entry.Data = newEntry.Data; }
```